# TypeScript Discriminated Union - Variable Used Before Assigned after Exhaustive If Statements

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I am writing some code using TypeScript's discriminated union feature. I am exhaustively checking the "type" property for each type in an `if-else if` structure and assigning a variable using logic in each block. Then, I am returning the variable. However, I am getting an error about the returned variable being used before it is assigned. The code follows this structure (this is a really simple example demonstrating the problem since my actual code is much more complex):

```
interface One
{
  num   : "one";
  value : string;
}

interface Two
{
  num   : "two";
  value : number;
}

interface SomeComplexObject
{
  // Complex properties
}

type Num  = One | Two;

function isOne(
  obj : Num
) : SomeComplexObject
{
  let complex : SomeComplexObject;

  if (obj.num === "one")
  {
    // Create a complex object with one set of parameters
  }
  else if (obj.num === "two")
  {
    // Create a complex object with a second set of parameters
  }

  return complex;
}
```

My first thought was to add a final `else` to throw an error saying that (in this case) the value for `num` is invalid, but since the other conditions are exhaustive, `obj` is of type `never` and cannot be used.

I could throw a super generic error and be done with it, but I am wondering why the compiler thinks `complex` could be undefined but at the same time recognize that the conditions are exhaustive. Is there something I am missing?

**Edit**: My original example seems to have caused some confusion. I updated it to hopefully be more representative of the actual problem.

Comment: Why not inilialise `let isOne = false` and then based on the check flip it to `true`? If the check fails then it's most definitely *not* `One`, after all, so it seems incorrect to make it an error condition.

Comment: Just replace `else if (obj.num === "two")` by `else`, then it should work flawlessly. `if`/`else if` can also mean, no condition is met, so you have `isOne` uninitialized (which can't be the case here, but apparently the compiler cannot figure that out.

Comment: @VLAZ There is no simple default in the actual code. The actual code uses Three.js Meshes, not booleans. So, creating defaults that will not be used is wasteful performance-wise.

Comment: @ford04 That becomes a slippery slope as I add more types. This example only shows 2, but in reality that number could grow. I want to make sure these objects are created if and only if the type is an exact match to prevent any future bugs.

Comment: Then it seems your code is not representative of your problem. I thought the issue was doing a check to find out if something is or isn't a given type. In that case, you can only check if it *is*, by definition if the check fails, then it isn't.

Comment: You could also use an [exhaustive switch](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking).

Comment: As @VLAZ said. If you are checking for a certain condition, since `boolean` has (should have) only two values, the object you are passing in may either satisfy the condition or not.  This is an `if`/`else` by definition

Comment: @VRoxa I have updated my example. It seems people may have been focusing on the boolean more than the actual problem. The type of the variable is inconsequential to the problem.

Comment: That's a completely new question, indeed, :)

Answer (score 0):

I handle these sorts of scenarios one of two ways. Usually go with the exhaustive switch.

```
interface One {
  num   : "one";
  value : string;
}

interface Two {
  num   : "two";
  value : number;
}

interface SomeComplexObject {
  // Complex properties
}

type Num = One | Two;

// Exhaustive Switch
function isOne(obj : Num) : SomeComplexObject {
    let complex: SomeComplexObject;

    switch (obj.num) {
        case "one":
            complex = {};
        case "two":
            complex = {};
    }

    return complex;
}

// Cast obj to any in `never` case
function isOne2(obj : Num) : SomeComplexObject {
    let complex: SomeComplexObject;

    if (obj.num === "one") {
        complex = {};
    } else if (obj.num === "two") {
        complex = {};
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Unknown object type ${(obj as any).num}`)
    }

    return complex;
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDOSAVwFs9kAuZAIgHsNKBuXZANzgBsCUKBnMKUAOaMAvtmyhIsRCgAqAd2rIceQiTwVKYBQyasOXfMQBG0EWInR4SZAGVqRCAGF7ABzYQAHqiMArCAjAlJgB6YORnIjdPZBcoahdoMGAIbmxRbDAATwTkADliZABeNAxkAB9keWpGbFDkAFEPAAs4Al5gZhQbOWAwBCbsGAIQAOBaZGBudAgACmpfcjziAEpFuwcIqK9ff0DlUndAhFd3Dwp1pxPPbz8AmtJkbh6%20puQ53wA6VVX9h7wEODcFA0OhkJh-P7HSKnIpKYSMCH-QHArTUShgxGQq4eWGYeHg5DpB5QCBgAhQEDIKFbMyDYajcaTaYAJnePkW%20SIq3O9ku0OuOwCQQehyp2J5G2xN1291IwBgb3mPi%20BUKaqotAglB%20BIe1JhxTxCNIwmQEDYQImCrZKpIauKmm0Osx%20uihvxD1N5stvz%20YCacTk%20AgQfqUDiUBmAAMAKogADWIGockpSt2yCyOQAJJg2chAfmQJllrbhFHlgSiaQSWSKWL%20R4REA)